# Separate objects in a point cloud

Tags: matlab, k-means, point-clouds, printer-control-language, octree

I am looking to Separate a point cloud into unconnected objects, I have 
tried using k-means algorithm, but it didn't do the whole job.
I'm looking to improve the results shown in the picture i added.
any thoughts or directions?
[My cloud, separated using k-means](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18S5S.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into Euclidean Segmentation, for which an algorithm is given on this page: http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cluster_extraction.php. PCL also provides a built-in implementation.